# Refining Saxon outuput

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-processing, text-formatting, xml

As a follow-up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656991/how-can-xpath-functions-be-expressed-to-output-each-input-element), I now have the following command:

```bsh
set +H && java -cp saxon-he-10.5.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -config:saxon.xml -s:rss.xml -qs:'//item/link!substring-after(., "_")'
```

**saxon.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
     For documentation on the contents of a Saxon configuration file, see
     http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/configuration/configuration-file/index.html
-->
<configuration edition="HE" xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration config.xsd">
  <global optimizationLevel="10"
          stripSpace="ignorable"
          recoveryPolicy="doNotRecover"
          dtdValidationRecoverable="no" />
</configuration>
```

How can this be tweaked to get my desired output?

**Desired Output**

```
92.204.241.167
181.24.239.244
193.243.195.66
```

**Present Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>92.204.241.167 181.24.239.244 193.243.195.66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify serialization properties either on the command line, or as part of the query itself, or in the configuration file. On the command line, use for example

```
!indent=yes
```

remembering that with some shells the `!` needs to be escaped as `\!`.

Within the query, use for example `declare option output:indent "yes";`.

In the configuration file, specify `<serialization indent="yes"/>`

The serialization parameters that you could consider here include:

- `method=text` - suppresses the XML declaration and prevents escaping
  of special characters such as `&`.
- `omit-xml-declaration=yes` - suppresses the XML declaration but does
  not prevent escaping
- `item-separator=\n` - uses a newline rather than a single space as
  the separator between items. The problem here is how to represent the
  newline. With the shell, `\n` is the most likely candidate, but it
  will probably need to be in quotes and it might vary from one shell
  to another. Within the query, or within the configuration file it
  will need to be written as `&#xa;`.

Finally, as an alternative to using the item-separator serialization property, you could introduce the newlines as part of the query itself, by writing it as

```
(//item/link!substring-after(., "_")) => string-join("&#xa;")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! After running these I noticed a final newline isn't appended. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: If you want a newline after every item including the last, try `(//item/link!(substring-after(., "_")||"&#xa;")`